# Spark cluster on EC2 is using only one node

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I use [flintrock](https://github.com/nchammas/flintrock) to launch a Spark cluster with 8+1 nodes on Amazon EC2.

```
> flintrock --config config.yaml launch cluster-8nodes
```

Then I use flintrock to login to the cluster:

```
> flintrock --config config.yaml login cluster-8nodes
```

The job I'm running is essentially this simple bigram counting code on a large text file:

```
@contextmanager
def use_spark_context(appName):
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName) 
    spark_context = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    try:
        print("starting ", appName)
        yield spark_context
    finally:
        spark_context.stop()
        print("stopping ", appName)

with use_spark_context("AppName") as spark:
    text_file = spark.textFile(text_path)
    bigrams = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(".")) \
                       .map(lambda line: line.strip().split(" ")) \
                       .flatMap(lambda xs: (tuple(x) for x in zip(xs, xs[1:])))
    counts = bigrams.map(lambda bigram: (bigram, 1)) \
            .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
            .filter(lambda bigram: bigram in name_bigrams) \
            .collect()
```

It is saved to a .py file and submitted as follows after login via flintrock:

```
> PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 spark-submit --num-executors 8 my_job.py --input data/bigtext.txt
```

The program seems to run fine and produces the following output. However, all of the nodes except one are idling. Shouldn't this setup distribute the job among the 8 nodes of the cluster?

```
18/06/08 09:50:48 INFO Executor: Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10). 1998 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/08 09:50:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 12.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12, localhost, executor driver, partition 12, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4851 bytes)
18/06/08 09:50:48 INFO Executor: Running task 12.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12)
18/06/08 09:50:48 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) in 30285 ms on localhost (executor driver) (11/382)
18/06/08 09:50:48 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/ec2-user/data/enwiki-extract.txt:402653184+33554432
18/06/08 09:50:53 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 32160, boot = -586, init = 588, finish = 32158
18/06/08 09:50:54 INFO Executor: Finished task 11.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 11). 1998 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/08 09:50:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver, partition 13, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4851 bytes)
18/06/08 09:50:54 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 11.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 11) in 32785 ms on localhost (executor driver) (12/382)
18/06/08 09:50:54 INFO Executor: Running task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13)
18/06/08 09:50:54 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/ec2-user/data/enwiki-extract.txt:436207616+33554432
18/06/08 09:51:19 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 30232, boot = -571, init = 578, finish = 30225
18/06/08 09:51:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 12.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12). 1998 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/08 09:51:19 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 14.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 14, localhost, executor driver, partition 14, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4851 bytes)
18/06/08 09:51:19 INFO Executor: Running task 14.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 14)
18/06/08 09:51:19 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 12.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12) in 30794 ms on localhost (executor driver) (13/382)
18/06/08 09:51:19 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/ec2-user/data/enwiki-extract.txt:469762048+33554432
18/06/08 09:51:25 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 31385, boot = -608, init = 611, finish = 31382
18/06/08 09:51:26 INFO Executor: Finished task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13). 1998 bytes result sent to driver
18/06/08 09:51:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 15.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 15, localhost, executor driver, partition 15, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4851 bytes)
18/06/08 09:51:26 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13) in 32061 ms on localhost (executor driver) (14/382)
18/06/08 09:51:26 INFO Executor: Running task 15.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 15)
18/06/08 09:51:26 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/ec2-user/data/enwiki-extract.txt:503316480+33554432
```

EDIT: If I specify the master URL as output by `flintrock launch` to `spark-submit --master`, the job starts but fails because the input file that is stored locally on the login node is not found:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 30, 172.31.28.28, executor 5): java.io.FileNo$
FoundException: File file:/home/ec2-user/data/enwiki-extract.txt does not exist
```

Isn't the login node also the master node? My assumption is that the master will read the file and distribute its partitions to the worker nodes.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests that you actually connect to the cluster. The code you have (hard to say without seeing `use_spark_context`) suggests you use `local` mode.

Comment: @user8371915 added code for `use_spark_context`. Do I need to edit the `SparkConf` to get out of local mode?

Comment: It is just a guess. Could you check `sc.master`? I pretty sure Flintrock should write master URL to the config though.

Comment: Note that it also says `executor driver` instead of `executor XX`

Comment: You are right, `sc.master` is `'local[*]'`. I guess I need a pointer to documentation describing how to setup the cluster in distributed mode. I assumed `flintrock` would configure this out of the box.

Comment: @user8371915 I guess the trick is to specify the master in `spark-submit`? Where do I find the master URL?

Comment: My understanding is that Flintrock should configure things without any further intervention. But [this](http://heather.miller.am/blog/launching-a-spark-cluster-part-1.html) (linked from the official git repo) shows similar problem,  if I am not mistaken. Maybe Nicholas Chammas or someone who is more familiar with Flintrock will be able to shed some light on this. Maybe you can check `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` or `SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf`

Comment: @user8371915 Check for what? `spark-defaults.conf` contains only `spark.jars.packages    org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3`

Comment: For `spark.master` settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `spark-submit` starts Spark in local mode. What worked was specifying the master via `--master spark://<masterURL>:7077` and set `--num-executors` to at least the number of worker nodes, depending on the cluster configuration.

Also, every node of the cluster needs a full local copy of the file in this case. This was unexpected to me at first, since I assumed that Spark would distribute the partitions of the file to the workers automatically via the network.